# How can we reach claims in fiber.context custom middleware?

Tags: go, go-fiber

I want to set claims to fiber.context. But I got an error in 3th line that is ***jwt.Token** is empty. How can I reach token or claims ? Or do you have an advice to use anything else.

```
func RoleMiddleware() func(*fiber.Ctx) { //change name
        return func(ctx *fiber.Ctx) {
            user := ctx.Locals("user").(*jwt.Token)
            claims := user.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims)
            ctx.Locals("id", int(claims["id"].(float64)))
            ctx.Locals("is_api", claims["is_api"])
            ctx.Locals("is_admin", claims["is_admin"])
            ctx.Locals("is_super_admin", claims["is_super_admin"])
        }
    }
```

I will use this for example in my user_controller:
`user_id := ctx.Locals("id").(int)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a complete JWT exmaple implementation in gofiber recipes repo.

link: https://github.com/gofiber/recipes/tree/master/jwt

In short.

```
product := api.Group("/product")
product.Get("/", handler.GetAllProducts)
product.Get("/:id", handler.GetProduct)
product.Post("/", middleware.Protected(), handler.CreateProduct)
product.Delete("/:id", middleware.Protected(), handler.DeleteProduct)
```

- Make sure you're using the filter on each protected route exactly as in the example:

Properly with `middleware.Protected()` so JWT token should be available in your handler `ctx.Locals`